# Trouble scrubbing a txt in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Often we receive .txt delimited by fixed character lengths, but this time I'm having to work with a .txt file that is intended for print. This file needs to be parsed into fields in MS Access so we can run it against other tables. Usually a quick `LTRIM()`followed by fixed character lengths works fine, but there appears to be "ghost" characters in this text file that is throwing off some rows and not others. I've also tried an `if isnumeric()` to verify the first row, but this is giving unexpected results as well.

I've tried converting the file to UTF-8 to get rid of these hidden characters and `isnumeric()` flaws that aren't caught by `LTRIM()`, but that didn't work. I've opened the file in a coding tool (Notepad++) to view hidden characters, but nothing appeared. Is there another way to clean the data file so that the characters appear exactly as I see them through Notepad?

Comment: First you need to know what the _ghost_ characters are. Enable viewing hidden characters in a text editor like notepad++ to discover what the invisible characters are.  You can also use the `Asc()` function to get the ascii code of a character.

Comment: Notepad++ did not show anything new except CR and FR. I did however find a solution that I will post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing a solution [here](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=144810), a `Clean()` function inserted at the same time as `LTRIM()` resolved the issue. Since Access doesn't have the same `Clean()` function as Excel, one had to be created with the following:

```
Public Function Clean(InString As String) As String
'-- Returns only printable characters from InString
   Dim x As Integer
   For x = 1 To Len(InString)
      If Asc(Mid(InString, x, 1)) > 31 And Asc(Mid(InString, x, 1)) < 127 Then
         Clean = Clean & Mid(InString, x, 1)
      End If
   Next x

End Function
```